# Destroy user - with custom authentication (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, action

Quick question: I was following this tutorial where they built user authentication system instead of using devise.

My issue is the tutorial misses the destroy action in which devise has ready and does so well.

My create action is

**User_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  if @user.valid?
    flash[:notice] = "You've successfully Created Your Account! Welcome!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Opps Something went bad, :/ Try again please"
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

I really hope this is not a total nuub question event though I am one. But can somebody offer some tips for a destroy action ? and also how would that action appear in routes and through a link_to method.  I want to create a deactivate page that gives a send off and the user is able to cancel their account. Any cool tips toward the deactivate page on the side will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Hartl rails tutorial covers this quite well IMO. Once you have the destroy action defined in your controller, you could create a link to deactivate their account calling the destroy action and redirect to the home page, or a goodbye page. As long as users is listed as a resource in your routes, you shouldn't need to modify your routes as DELETE is a standard CRUD command.

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users

for example:

user_controller

```
def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
end
```

view

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the deactivate page, maybe you can add a boolean column in your users table, say `is_active`,
and another controller action for deactivation, say `deactivate`, which will just set the is_active column as false for that user.
see sample routes.rb for the route.

@ncarroll 's sample is correct, for the routes, if you have in your `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    put :deactivate
  end
end
```

This will automatically create routes for the RESTful actions, which includes `destroy`.